# How to create custom Tables in Salesforce

Tags: soql

I recently started Learning SOQL a few days ago, watched some videos on youtube. Like Coming from a Programming angle and point of view, you need to, first of all, create tables (PHPMyAdmin / SQL Server Management Studio) using these tools in their servers respectively (MYSQL / MSSQL)
I am trying to do the same in Salesforce, Create a Custom Table that I can Query Later. if possible, use for REST / SOAP API in salesforce?

Like I said before, I am quite new to Salesforce. I need direction

**Edits**

I have seen Fields and Relationships
Clicked on it nd it prompted me to a new Page

Now I want to set the following data for instance

```
Fullname
Address
Address2
State
Zip
Email
Telephone 
Gender
NationalID
Account_type
AccountNumber
Balance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables in Salesforce are known as sObjects (Salesforce Objects). You can create them in Setup > Object Manager, or you can use the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm), although this is largely an advanced topic; it's easier to copy an sObject or a field from an existing configuration, which means using the UI. Once you create an sObject, you can use the REST and SOAP APIs to insert, update, delete, and undelete these records. You generally need to use the Metadata API to create, update, or delete fields, however. This is in contrast to normal SQL, where you'd do things like `CREATE TABLE`, `UPDATE TABLE`, and `DROP TABLE`.

Comment: Done. So how do i go about creating the columns?

Comment: @Jin On the Object Manager page, choose your new sObject, and then click on Fields & Relationships. Click on New, you'll be taken to a short 3-4 page wizard to specify the type, name, label, default value, required/index values, profile properties (e.g. which users can view/edit the field/column), and which page layouts it should be displayed on.

Comment: Please See edits sir @sfdcfox

Comment: @Jin It sounds like you want default features? You might want to look at Accounts, Contacts, and Opportunities. Most of this is already built for you.

Comment: @sfdfox, No sir. I do not want it. I want something I can run custom.

Comment: @Jin Well, you can, certainly. Especially if you're learning. You have to create each field individually.